# Manage many HTTP requests with Retrofit 2 and Otto

Tags: android, retrofit2, otto

I'm creating the back-end of an Android application with Retrofit 2 and Otto and it involves managing a number of HTTP post request (say, 50). My questions are:

1) Since each request returns a different JSON, is it appropriate to create a pojo to handle the body of each request or is there a better approach to handle this?

2) Additionally, I'm using an event bus, so that the flow is:

UI event -> main thread -> event -> network manager (client) -> event -> main thread -> UI

Where should I best deal with the data management? For example, if I want to populate a database with the info returned by the post request, should I do something like:

UI event -> main thread -> event -> network manager (client) -> DB population -> event -> main thread (fetches the data from  the DB) -> UI

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First question - I think it's doesnt matter
For example 
I use POJO which contains all json answers, but it contain response code which help me recognise which variables I shouldn't use
It helped me make my code more simple